# what is "they found a typo in the CMS block",I got a question in a magento 2 practice test, Can any one clarify this?

Tags: magento2, certification

You have written a free module that is distributed on GitHub. Unfortunately, people are reporting that they found a typo in the CMS block.

How do you get this resolved?

Answers( radio button type)

-> Tell users to update the content.

-> Switch to hard coding the value into your module and release an update.

-> Create a new data patch.

-> Fix the content in your module's UpgradeData class.

What is the meaning of **" they found a typo in the CMS block"**.

Since this is a magento forum , i hope this question is eligible to ask and get support from the expert.Please some one explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In English, sometimes the word “typo” is used as a shortcut for the phrase “typographical error.”

[Dictionary.com defines typographical error](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/typographical-error) as

> an error in printed or typewritten matter resulting from striking the improper key of a keyboard, from mechanical failure, or the like.

Basically, it’s  any word or phrase that has been mis-typed or misspelled or has been in some way erroneously entered into the content management system.

In the specific example, the question is indicating that after you published your module, someone found a typographical error in the content in a CMS Block that your module uses to display content and you are being asked how to best correct that typographical error.

I’ll leave it as an exercise for the readers to choose the best answer, but for an example, imagine that your CMS Block SHOULD read:

“This is sample text my module needs to display to a user.”

BUT INSTEAD READS:

“This is smample texf mo madule nerfa to dispkay to a user.”

The question is saying that some people have reported typos in the CMS block your module created and uses and is asking you how to best fix the typographical errors.

Comment: thank you for your explanation